# Getting error while Webscraping for a requests.post method

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to extract the data for a state office in "DELHI'. However, my code is not working. I am sure the data parameters are incorrect in my python code. I have imported all the required libraries like pandas, beautifulSoup, requests etc before running the code.

```
r = requests.get('https://search.epfindia.gov.in/locate_office/office_location.php')
def get_all_forms(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    return soup.find_all('form')
details = {}
action = form.attrs.get("action").lower()
method = form.attrs.get("method", "get").lower()
State_value = "Delhi"
district_value = "East Delhi"
Pin_value = "110032"
inputs = [State_value, district_value, Pin_value]
fetchdata = requests.post(form, data = inputs)
print (fetchdata.text)
```

The website looks like this :
https://search.epfindia.gov.in/locate_office/office_location.php

In the form, there are a State/UT, District and PIN/Area field. Each State has respective districts. PIN/Area field is not visible, but for some States like "DELHI", after selecting District field, the PIN/Area field appears and we need to select appropriate PIN Code. After selecting the options from dropdown, we need to submit the form and it gives a filtered table for selected options.

I am trying to extract all the office address present in a districts of a State. Please help me building the code. If you write me the code, then I'll study the code and understand where I went wrong. Otherwise if there is any study material on such type of webscraping through web-form post method please tell me. I will study them and try again. Thank you.

Comment: _However, my code is not working_ This doesn't tell us much.  Instead of saying "it isn't working", tell us what the code _actually does_, and explain how that is different from what you _wanted_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data for specific PIN you can use this example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


post_url = "https://search.epfindia.gov.in/locate_office/resulttable.php"
data = {
    "submit1": "submit1",
    "state": "DELHI",
    "district": "EAST DELHI",
    "pin_area": "110032",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(post_url, data=data).content, "html.parser")

for td in soup.select("td.large_font"):
    print(td.text)
```

Prints:

```
DSIIDC Facility Centre Building, Flatted Factory Complex,
2nd & 3rd Floor, Jhilmil Industrial Area,
New Delhi, DELHI
Email: sro.laxminagar@epfindia.gov.in

Bhavishya Nidhi Bhawan, 8 th Floor, 28,Community Centre,
Wazirpur Industrial Area,
Delhi, DELHI
Email: acc.dlut@epfindia.gov.in
```